# Windows (2016) Task Scheduler does not always fire repeated triggers

Tags: windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I have a pair of scheduled tasks that start at 6:00 and 6:03 respectively each day and repeat every 15 minutes for 18 hours.  This has worked on one (2008R2) server for years, but that server is retiring being replaced by a 2016 server.  I exported and imported the tasks to the new 2016 server.  When I enabled the first task (6:00), it ran fine through the first day, ran the task at 6:00 the next day, but didn't run any repeats at 6:15, 6:30, 6:45, 7:00, 7:15 which is when I noticed this.

I killed the relevant svchost process shortly after 7:30, Windows restarted its services and the schedule ran from 7:45 throughout the rest of the day.  The machine was rebooted at 10:30 PM, and the schedule ran fine for several more days.  I then enabled the second task (6:03) yesterday.  Both ran fine for the rest of yesterday.  This morning, the 6:00 and 6:03 tasks both ran.  But not the 6:15, 6:18, 6:30 etc.  I again killed the svchost and the next iteration of both scheduled tasks ran.

The Event Log indicates that both tasks completed their 6:00/6:03 runs successfully.  It also indicates other (unrelated) tasks have been triggered, including time-based triggers, during the time these repeating triggers didn't work.  There is no sign that the tasks in question exist at all in the event log (i.e. no failed triggers, just nothing).

Since restarting the service corrects the issue, it appears that they are properly set up.  How would you troubleshoot this?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. There is a similar question here -- https://serverfault.com/q/399991/450038 -- with a bunch of potential answers. Noe of them look like an exact match to what you are seeing, but if you read through them, something might jump out at you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Doug.  I've gone through the suggestions from that question in stages and none have yet to resolve the issue for me.  Very weird.